# Change the tag container background color in the stack apps profile page

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, stackapps

On the [Stack Apps profile page](https://stackapps.com/users/current?tab=profile), the **Top Tags** section's tag container row almost has the same color as the background color. So the **Top Tags** section is not looking nice.

[image: Top tags - not valid background color]

Changing the tag container background color will make the section more readable. Like the below:

[image: Top tags - valid background color]

So my request is, to change the tag container background color for better readability.